# Cannot load file error...but file definitely exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error message:

```
cannot load such file -- less (in /home/starkers/Documents/angular/vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less)
```

and yet in the console:

```
cat /home/starkers/Documents/angular/vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less"; 
@import "mixins.less";
...
```

I've restarted by server so what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rails asset pipeline can't serve `less` stylesheet file.

Add these to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

`bundle install` and then restarting server.

More details, check https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.
Cleaning up my public/assets and tmp/cache/development
and then restarting the server did the job for me.